# Using CFDocumentTypes, is there a way to download the specified file from safari?

Tags: iphone, plist, mobile-safari

I am using CFDocumentTypes and UTExportedType in my iphone plist to be able to download qif/ofx files straight to my application.

At the moment it can download them from the mailapp. Is there any way to get them to download from safari as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in iPhone OS 3.2 for iPad, but it's possible in iOS 4.0 for iPhone. So I guess this will be available when iOS 4 for iPad comes out.